# How does CA verify if i own the domain if i ask it to sign my CSR

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, certificate, keytool

What will happen if I make a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for a domain which I don't own and ask a CA to sign my CSR?

Comment: The CA _never_ signs a CSR. It signs a _certificate_ which is _based on_ a CSR but is not at all the same as the CSR.

Comment: Nothing happens at the technical step of issuing the certificate (you can try yourself, you can be a CA). However, CAs are mandated to **validate** the request before issuing the certificate. Validating the request can be done in multiple ways (like with DNS or HTTP queries) but the aim is always to find out if you really control the domain for which you asked a certificate to be generated. Some certificates provider even hide the CSR step for you: they generate a private key in your browser, you choose the domain, they create the data and send it to the CA for validation and then issuance.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the CA and type of the certificate. Automated CAs like LetsEncrypt have client scripts that will publish something to the domain (DNS, Web etc.) to authenticate it. Some might email an address you give them at that domain and expect to talk to you. Some really old-school CAs might look up the business name in the phone book and call.

Comment: In addition nowadays if the owner has set a [CAA record in DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) and you submit to any _other_ CA they must reject your request; the owner has already obtained a cert from that CA, which is likely, and you submit there they will see your new request is different from the owner's previous request.

Comment: "Some really old-school CAs might look up the business name in the phone book and call. " Why is that old school? There are various validation methods, and it also depends on the type of certificate (DV vs OV vs EV). Everything is spelled out in the CABForum guidelines at https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.9.pdf for the current version and see notably the section 3.2 about validation.